# Getting progress of numpy operations?

Tags: python, numpy

I compute pseudoinverses of huge matrices all the time with `np.linalg.pinv`. What bothers me is I never know how long this operation will take.

Is there a way of getting the progress of my `np.linalg.pinv`? I think this might be possible, probably by adding a hook to the function's inner loop?

I hope to find a non-invasive way where I don't have to go inside the function and edit the source code, but if that's the only way, it's better than nothing!

Comment: `pinv` works by 1st performing a singular value decomposition (svd), which uses very specialized c-libraries (so editing the source would be incredibly hard). The time complexity is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) (in this case I think it is O(mn**2)) and some benchmarking [here](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2012/singular-value-decomposition-in-scipy/). I hope at least this can help you get a coarse time estimate